# Как преобразовать упоминания в ссылки с помощью регулярного выражения

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться с регулярными выражениями. Нужно, чтобы все слова, начинающиеся на `@`, делались ссылкой.

Получилось такое регулярное выражение:

```
$text = preg_replace('/\s@(.*)[^\s\,\.]+/ui', ' <a href="https://domen.ru/$1">@$1</a>', $text);
```

Однако если в тексте встречаются два пробела, то всё ломается. Например при обработке

```php
@Tript  по поводу заказа
```

почему-то выдаётся

```php
<a href=\"https://domen.ru/Tript  по поводу заказќ">@Tript  по поводу заказм/a>
```

Если один пробел, то все работает нормально, хотя `+` — это же квантификатор, обозначающий одно или более вхождений.

Comment: Может, `preg_replace('~(?<!\S)@([^\s,.]+)~u', '<a href="https://domen.ru/$1">$0</a>', $text)`?

Comment: спасибо, помогло

Comment: Давайте лучше я оформлю ответ, с объяснением и примером.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы можете использовать

```php
$text = preg_replace('~(?<!\S)@([^\s,.]+)~u', '<a href="https://domen.ru/$1">$0</a>', $text);
```

Модификатор `u` необходим, так как он включает опцию `(*UTF)` библиотеки PCRE, благодаря которой строка обрабатывается как массив символов Юникода, а не обчных байтов.

См. [пример работы выражения](https://regex101.com/r/uJtdI5/1).

*Значение выражения*:

- `(?<!\S)` - блок предварительного просмотра назад, требует отсутствия непробельного символа сразу перед текущей позицией в строке
- `@`  - символ `@`
- `([^\s,.]+)` - Захватывающая подмаска №1: один и более пробельных символов (`\s`), запятых (`,`) и точек (`.`).

В шаблоне замены $0 соответствует всему совпадению, а $1 — только значению первой подмаски.

См. [пример работы кода на PHP](https://ideone.com/SPYZ7j):

```php
<?php
 
$text = '@Tript по поводу заказа';
$text = preg_replace('~(?<!\S)@([^\s,.]+)~u', '<a href="https://' . 'domen.ru/$1">$0</a>', $text);
echo $text;
// -> <a href="https://domen.ru/Tript">@Tript</a> по поводу заказа
```

Answer (score -1):

```
preg_replace('~(?<!\S)@([^\s,.]+)~u', '<a href="https://domen.ru/$1">$0</a>', $text)
```

работает.
Спасибо Wiktor Stribiżew

Comment: Удалите, пожалуйста, и примите мой ответ как правильный, раз уж он вам помог.

Comment: Еще раз спасибо